# Geoserver geowebcache is not generating tiles for part of layer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, wmts

I've got a layer in Geoserver which is cached using GeoWebCache. For the largest part of the layer bounding box, I can zoom in on any area where it generates the tiles on the fly within a second. But for one part of the same layer, when I zoom in, the tiles are not generated and the map stays blurry (see image below). Even when zooming in further nothing happens. I already tried to truncate all tiles and generate them again. I also restarted geoserver. It also does not matter which coordinate system / epsg I'm using.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Here is a part of the logfile:

```
delta computed in 288us for D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:14:25,867 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps] - Removing statuses matching [[[ NOT [ completionTime IS NULL ] ] AND [ completionTime Before 2022-06-15T20:09Z ]] AND [[ NOT [ lastUpdated IS NULL ] ] AND [ lastUpdated Before 2022-06-15T20:09Z ]]]
2022-06-15 20:14:30,672 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:14:30,672 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 269us for D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:14:35,676 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
...
2022-06-15 20:14:45,690 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 248us for D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:14:50,704 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:14:50,704 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 302us for D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:14:55,709 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:15:20,755 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:15:20,755 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 254us for D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:15:25,759 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:15:25,759 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 259us for D:\GeoserverDataDir\gwc-layers
2022-06-15 20:15:25,884 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wps] - Removing statuses matching [[[ NOT [ completionTime IS NULL ] ] AND [ completionTime Before 2022-06-15T20:10Z ]] AND [[ NOT [ lastUpdated IS NULL ] ] AND [ lastUpdated Before 2022-06-15T20:10Z ]]]
2022-06-15 20:15:26,544 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 37-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&lines=1000'; against '/web/**'
2022-06-15 20:15:26,544 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 37-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&lines=1000 with /web/**
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: @IanTurton, thanks for your reply. I completely missed your comment a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recreated the complete layer group in Geoserver. All included layers and stylings are identital, but somehow the WMTS does work now. So problem 'solved' for now.